# UILabelのframeをコードでiphone6,iphone6plusに適用させたい

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

UILabel以外の部品はstoryboardで作成し、storyboardでAutoLayoutを適用したのですが、UILabelをコードで生成せざるをえない状況にありまして、iphone6,iphone6plusになると位置がずれてしまいます。デフォルトのiphone5では正常な位置にあります。
コードで生成したUILabelをihone6,iphone6plusでも理想としてる位置に生成する方法はありますでしょうか。サンプルなどで説明していただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

コードで生成するUILabelに、コードからAuto Layoutを設定するというのが通常の対処方法です。この方法であれば、Auto Layoutでできる事はすべて同じように実現できます。ただ、コードでやるのは少し面倒なのがデメリットです。

少し手抜きの対応方法として、UILabelを置きたい位置にダミーのViewを設置しておく方法があります。

ダミーのViewにAuto Layoutを設定して、最終的に必要となるUILabelの位置やサイズを満たすようにしておきます。コードからは、そのViewにUILabelをaddSubviewするようにします。

これで、UILabelの位置はダミーのViewの位置が基準となるため、位置がずれる問題に関しては対応できるかと思われます。（サイズについても、autoresizingMaskを使えば対応できたりします）

コードとしてはこんな感じになります。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    /// UILabelの位置に置いたダミーのView
    @IBOutlet weak var baseView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        /// コードからUILabelを生成
        let re = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 60)
        let label = UILabel(frame: re)
        label.text = "Test label"
        baseView.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

Comment: すいません、いまいち、なぜ、UIViewを置いた上にUILabelに適用してconstraintが適用できるのか理解しかねております。ご丁寧に返答いただいたのに大変失礼ではありますが、どうしてそうなるか説明していだだくことはできますでしょうか。

Comment: 回答文を修正しましたので、そちらを参照してください。